# yii user-management edit field

Tags: yii

I have managed to set-up yii-user-management. Thanks to help from here.

However, when I am in profile/fields/admin .

I click on edit field and then change the field from required 'no' to 'yes' in the dropdown, then save, but nothing happens.

I also get :

CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(0) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0' at line 1. The SQL statement executed was: ALTER TABLE profile ADD `` (0) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0

When creating a field.

Let me know if you need some code or files. Any help appreciated.

Here is the profile/models/YumProfileField.php

```
class YumProfileField extends YumActiveRecord
{
const VISIBLE_HIDDEN=0;
const VISIBLE_ONLY_OWNER=1;
const VISIBLE_REGISTER_USER=2;
const VISIBLE_USER_DECISION=3;
const VISIBLE_PUBLIC=4; // Field is public even if the user decides to hide it

/**
 * Returns the static model of the specified AR class.
 * @param string $className
 * @return YumProfileField
 */
public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
{
    return parent::model($className);
}

public function isPublic($user = null) {
    if($user == null)
        $user = Yii::app()->user->id;

    if(!$this->visible)
        return false;

    if($privacy = YumUser::model()->findByPk($user)->privacy) {
        if($privacy->public_profile_fields & pow(2, $this->id))
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}

public function tableName()
{
    $this->_tableName = Yum::module('profile')->profileFieldTable;
    return $this->_tableName;
}
public function scopes()
{
    return array(
            'forAll'=>array(
                'condition'=>'visible='.self::VISIBLE_PUBLIC,
                ),
            'forUser'=>array(
                'condition'=>'visible>='.self::VISIBLE_REGISTER_USER,
                ),
            'forOwner'=>array(
                'condition'=>'visible>='.self::VISIBLE_ONLY_OWNER,
                ),
            );
}

public static function itemAlias($type,$code=NULL) {
    $_items = array(
            'field_type' => array(
                'INTEGER' => Yum::t('INTEGER'),
                'VARCHAR' => Yum::t( 'VARCHAR'),
                'TEXT'=> Yum::t( 'TEXT'),
                'DATE'=> Yum::t( 'DATE'),
                'DROPDOWNLIST' => Yum::t('DROPDOWNLIST'),
                'FLOAT'=> Yum::t('FLOAT'),
                'BOOL'=> Yum::t('BOOL'),
                'BLOB'=> Yum::t('BLOB'),
                'BINARY'=> Yum::t('BINARY'),
                'FILE'=> 'FILE',
                ),
            'required' => array(
                '0' => Yum::t('No'),
                '1' => Yum::t('Yes'),
                ),
            'visible' => array(
                self::VISIBLE_USER_DECISION => Yum::t('Let the user choose in privacy settings'),
                self::VISIBLE_PUBLIC => Yum::t('For all'),
                self::VISIBLE_REGISTER_USER => Yum::t('Registered users'),
                self::VISIBLE_ONLY_OWNER => Yum::t('Only owner'),
                self::VISIBLE_HIDDEN => Yum::t('Hidden'),
                ),
            );
    if (isset($code))
        return isset($_items[$type][$code]) ? $_items[$type][$code] : false;
    else
        return isset($_items[$type]) ? $_items[$type] : false;
}
}
```

The YumFieldsController:

```
class YumFieldsController extends YumController
{
const PAGE_SIZE=10;

public function accessRules()
{
    return array(
        array('allow', 
            'actions'=>array('index', 'create', 'update', 'view', 'admin','delete'),
            'users'=>array(Yii::app()->user->name),
            'expression' => 'Yii::app()->user->isAdmin()'
            ),
        array('deny',  // deny all users
            'users'=>array('*'),
        ),
    );
}

public function actionView()
{
    $this->layout = Yum::module()->adminLayout;
    $this->render('view',array(
        'model'=>$this->loadModel('YumProfileField'),
    ));
}

public function actionCreate() {
    $this->layout = Yum::module()->adminLayout;
    $model = new YumProfileField;

    // add to group?
    if(isset($_GET['in_group']))
        $model->field_group_id=$_GET['in_group'];

    if(isset($_POST['YumProfileField'])) {
        $model->attributes = $_POST['YumProfileField'];

        $field_type = $model->field_type;
        if($field_type == 'DROPDOWNLIST')
            $field_type = 'INTEGER';

        if($model->validate()) {
            $sql = 'ALTER TABLE '.YumProfile::model()->tableName().' ADD `'.$model->varname.'` ';
            $sql .= $field_type;
            if ($field_type!='TEXT' && $field_type!='DATE')
                $sql .= '('.$model->field_size.')';
            $sql .= ' NOT NULL ';
            if ($model->default)
                $sql .= " DEFAULT '".$model->default."'";
            else
                $sql .= (($field_type =='TEXT' || $model->field_type=='VARCHAR')?" DEFAULT ''":" DEFAULT 0");

            $model->dbConnection->createCommand($sql)->execute();
            $model->save();
            $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
        }
    }

    $this->render('create',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
}

public function actionUpdate()
{
    $this->layout = Yum::module()->adminLayout;

    $model = $this->loadModel('YumProfileField');
    if(isset($_POST['YumProfileField']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['YumProfileField'];

        // ALTER TABLE `test` CHANGE `profiles` `field` INT( 10 ) NOT NULL 
        // ALTER TABLE `test` CHANGE `profiles` `description` INT( 1 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
        if($model->save())
            $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
    }

    $this->render('update',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
}

public function actionDelete()
{
    $this->layout = Yum::module()->adminLayout;
    if(Yii::app()->request->isPostRequest)
    {
        // we only allow deletion via POST request
        $model = $this->loadModel('YumProfileField');
        $sql = 'ALTER TABLE '.YumProfile::model()->tableName().' DROP `'.$model->varname.'`';
        if ($model->dbConnection->createCommand($sql)->execute()) {
            $model->delete();
        }

        if(!isset($_POST['ajax']))
            $this->redirect(array('index'));
    }
    else
        throw new CHttpException(400,'Invalid request. Please do not repeat this request again.');
}

public function actionIndex()
{
    $this->layout = Yum::module()->adminLayout;
    $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('YumProfileField', array(
        'pagination'=>array(
            'pageSize'=>self::PAGE_SIZE,
        ),
        'sort'=>array(
            'defaultOrder'=>'position',
        ),
    ));

    $this->render('index',array(
        'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    ));
}

public function actionAdmin()
{
    $this->layout = Yum::module()->adminLayout;

    $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('YumProfileField', array(
        'pagination'=>array(
            'pageSize'=>self::PAGE_SIZE,
        ),
        'sort'=>array(
            'defaultOrder'=>'position',
        ),
    ));

    $this->render('admin',array(
        'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    ));
}

}
```

YumProfile.php model

```
class YumProfile extends YumActiveRecord
{
const PRIVACY_PRIVATE = 'private';
const PRIVACY_PUBLIC = 'public';

/**
 * @var array of YumProfileFields
 */
static $fields=null;

public function init()
{
    parent::init();
    // load profile fields only once
    $this->loadProfileFields();
}

public function afterSave() {
    if($this->isNewRecord) 
        Yii::log(Yum::t( 'A profile been created: {profile}', array(
                        '{profile}'   =>json_encode($this->attributes))));
    else
        Yii::log(Yum::t( 'A profile been update: {profile}', array(
                        '{profile}' => json_encode($this->attributes))));

    return parent::afterSave();
}

public function recentComments($count = 3) {
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria->condition = 'id = ' .$this->id;
    $criteria->order = 'createtime DESC';
    $criteria->limit = $count;
    return YumProfileComment::model()->findAll($criteria);
}

public function beforeValidate() {
    if($this->isNewRecord)
        $this->timestamp = time();
    return parent::beforeValidate();
}

/**
 * @param string $className
 * @return YumProfile
 */
public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
{
    return parent::model($className);
}

// All fields that the user has activated in his privacy settings will
// be obtained and returned for the use in the profile view
public function getPublicFields() {
    if(!Yum::module('profile')->enablePrivacySetting)
        return false;

    $fields = array();

    if($privacy = YumUser::model()
            ->cache(500)
            ->with('privacy')
            ->findByPk($this->user_id)
            ->privacy->public_profile_fields) {
        $i = 1;
        foreach(YumProfileField::model()->cache(3600)->findAll() as $field) {
            if(
                    (($i & $privacy) 
                     && $field->visible != YumProfileField::VISIBLE_HIDDEN) 
                    || $field->visible == YumProfileField::VISIBLE_PUBLIC)
                $fields[] = $field;
            $i*=2;
        }
    }
    return $fields;
}

/**
 * Returns resolved table name 
 * @return string
 */
public function tableName()
{
    $this->_tableName = Yum::module('profile')->profileTable;
    return $this->_tableName;
}

public function rules()
{
    $required = array();
    $numerical = array();
    $rules = array();
    $safe = array();

    foreach (self::$fields as $field) {
        $field_rule = array();

        if ($field->required == 1)
            array_push($required, $field->varname);

        if ($field->field_type == 'int'
                || $field->field_type == 'FLOAT'
                || $field->field_type =='INTEGER'
                || $field->field_type =='BOOLEAN')
            array_push($numerical, $field->varname);

        if ($field->field_type == 'DROPDOWNLIST')
            array_push($safe, $field->varname);

        if ($field->field_type == 'VARCHAR' || $field->field_type == 'TEXT') {
            $field_rule = array($field->varname,
                    'length',
                    'max'=>$field->field_size,
                    'min' => $field->field_size_min);

            if ($field->error_message)
                $field_rule['message'] = Yum::t($field->error_message);

            array_push($rules,$field_rule);
        }

        if ($field->match) {
            $field_rule = array($field->varname,
                    'match',
                    'pattern' => $field->match);

            if ($field->error_message)
                $field_rule['message'] = Yum::t( $field->error_message);

            array_push($rules,$field_rule);
        }

        if ($field->range) {
            // allow using commas and semicolons
            $range=explode(';',$field->range);
            if(count($range)===1)
                $range=explode(',',$field->range);
            $field_rule = array($field->varname,'in','range' => $range);

            if ($field->error_message)
                $field_rule['message'] = Yum::t( $field->error_message);
            array_push($rules,$field_rule);
        }

        if ($field->other_validator) {
            $field_rule = array($field->varname,
                    $field->other_validator);

            if ($field->error_message)
                $field_rule['message'] = Yum::t( $field->error_message);
            array_push($rules, $field_rule);
        }

    }

    array_push($rules,
            array(implode(',',$required), 'required'));
    array_push($rules,
            array(implode(',',$numerical), 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true));
    array_push($rules,
            array(implode(',',$safe), 'safe'));

    $rules[] = array('allow_comments, show_friends', 'numerical');
    $rules[] = array('email', 'unique');
    $rules[] = array('email', 'CEmailValidator');
    $rules[] = array('privacy', 'safe');

    return $rules;
}

public function relations()
{
    $relations = array(
            'user' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'YumUser', 'user_id'),
            'comments' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'YumProfileComment', 'profile_id'),
            );

    $fields = Yii::app()->db->cache(3600)->createCommand(
            "select * from ".YumProfileField::model()->tableName()." where field_type = 'DROPDOWNLIST'")->queryAll();

    foreach($fields as $field) {
        $relations[ucfirst($field['varname'])] = array(
                self::BELONGS_TO, ucfirst($field['varname']), $field['varname']);

    }

    return $relations;
}

// Retrieve a list of all users that have commented my profile
// Do not show my own profile visit
public function getProfileCommentators() {
    $commentators = array();
    foreach($this->comments as $comment)
        if($comment->user_id != Yii::app()->user->id)
            $commentators[$comment->user_id] = $comment->user;

    return $commentators;
}

public function getProfileFields() {
    $fields = array();

    if(self::$fields)
        foreach(self::$fields as $field) {
            $varname = $field->varname;
            $fields[$varname] = Yum::t($varname);
        }
    return $fields;
}

public function name() {
    return sprintf('%s %s', $this->firstname, $this->lastname);
}

public function attributeLabels()
{
    $labels = array(
            'id' => Yum::t('Profile ID'),
            'user_id' => Yum::t('User ID'),
            'privacy' => Yum::t('Privacy'),
            'show_friends' => Yum::t('Show friends'),
            'allow_comments' => Yum::t('Allow profile comments'),
            );

    if(self::$fields)
        foreach (self::$fields as $field)
            $labels[$field->varname] = Yum::t($field->title);

    return $labels;
}

/**
 * Load profile fields.
 * Overwrite this method to get another set of fields
 * Makes use of cache so the amount of sql queries per request is reduced
 * @since 0.6
 * @return array of YumProfileFields or empty array
 */
public function loadProfileFields()
{
    if(self::$fields===null)
    {
        self::$fields=YumProfileField::model()->cache(3600)->findAll();
        if(self::$fields==null)
            self::$fields=array();
    }
    return self::$fields;
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like you're trying to add a column with no name or type? [MySQL ALTER TABLE examples](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table-examples.html).

Also, check your db user has permissions to `ALTER TABLE`.

Comment: Hi, thanks. The permissions are okay and I realise the sql error but was wondering how to correct the issue within the yii framework

Comment: depends on how you are calling the query, can you add the code that created the `ALTER TABLE` query?

Comment: Can we see your rules in your YumProfile model? It looks like the model is validating ok, but `$model->varname` is empty, as is `$model->field_type`, which seems a bit odd. What happens if you do a `var_dump($model->attributes);` after your `$model->attributes = $_POST['YumProfileField']` line?

Comment: array(16) { ["id"]=> string(1) "4" ["varname"]=> string(6) "street" ["title"]=> string(6) "Street" ["hint"]=> string(0) "" ["field_type"]=> string(7) "VARCHAR" ["field_size"]=> string(3) "255" ["field_size_min"]=> string(1) "0" ["required"]=> string(1)  "0" ["match"]=> string(0) "" ["range"]=> string(0) "" ["error_message"]=> string(0) "" ["other_validator"]=> string(0) "" ["default"]=> string(0) "" ["position"]=> string(1) "0" ["visible"]=> string(1) "3" ["related_field_name"]=> string(0) "" }     This was for edit fields. Chose to change required to yes but didn't register

Comment: very odd, does it output the same immediately after the `if($model->validate()) {` line? Before the `$sql = 'ALTER TABLE '.YumProfile::model()->tableName().' ADD '.$model->varname.' ';` line?

Comment: array(16) { ["varname"]=> string(0) "" ["title"]=> string(0) "" ["field_type"]=> string(0) "" ["field_size"]=> int(0) ["field_size_min"]=> int(0) ["required"]=> int(0) ["match"]=> string(0) "" ["range"]=> string(0) "" ["error_message"]=> string(0) "" ["other_validator"]=> string(0) "" ["default"]=> string(0) "" ["position"]=> int(0) ["visible"]=> int(0) ["related_field_name"]=> string(0) "" ["id"]=> NULL ["hint"]=> NULL }   After the above

Comment: ok, so there's a problem with your validation rules, for some reason it seems to be stripping all the content. Do you have any `beforeValidate()` or `afterValidate()` rules in your model? Also, check your `rules()` method in your model too to see if there are any issues there

Comment: Are you referring to the models above, because nothing in there.I have this file Profile.php Yii::import('application.modules.profile.models.YumProfile');
class Profile extends YumProfile {

 function rules() {
  $rules = parent::rules();
  $rules[] = array('about', 'required');
  return $rules;
 }
}

Comment: yeah, try removing the `beforeValidate()` method and see if you get any different results.

Comment: No luck I'm afraid. Still not posting data.

Comment: Hi Stu, any more thoughts on this?

Comment: with your application, can you call `$model->save()` in place of the `model->validate()`?

Comment: Hi, I changed this in the YumFieldsController, as suggested but still empty post.

Comment: very odd, I can't think what might be the problem, the validation process seems to be wiping the model... I'll have a think!

Comment: appreciate your efforts thanks. I think you also responded to the other annoying issue I have with guest users viewing profiles. Did yum really work out of the box for you?

Comment: ah yes, I use RBAC for access control and then customise my views myself, I've not tried using yum so can't comment on how to implement it unfortunately :( can only comment on the code I see

Comment: Anyone actually get yum to work for updating fields? Still not posting data changes to profileFields.

Comment: Failed to set unsafe attribute "varname" of "YumProfileField"

Comment: ah ok, then you need to either give that a setting in the `rules` method in your model or add that as a safe attribute, I see you've got quite a complicated rules set already! Here's a good article on massive assignment and rules: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/161/understanding-safe-validation-rules/

Comment: Thanks..Should the rules be in YumProfileFields (in which case there aren't any) not YumProfile(these are for profile form)? Sorry still find this all a bit confusing.

Comment: ah yes sorry, you have to define rules for each field in the DB if you want to massive assign variables to a model. So for example you need to define the db field as 'number', or 'string', or if there's no specific validation rules for a field, you can just define it as 'safe. Check out this wiki might help a little: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/56/ Although on a side note if there are no rules for a field being validated the validation should just return false, not wipe the whole lot!

Comment: Thanks. Yes I realised the lack of rules was doing this and just doing that now.

Comment: Hallelujah!  public function rules(){
  $rules = array();.....   in the YumProfileField.php. Sorted it out. Thanks very much for your help in this. Still struggling on the guest user access though. yum still seems to be a beta